# Doesn't htmlspecialchars() protect against javascript when calling in jquery .html() in result through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I wrote a php and jquery-ajax script that works good. But the following scripts work slow and I found that this type of script is vulnerable to XSS attack, I found something regarding it in this link's first answer [please see the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584189/when-used-correctly-is-htmlspecialchars-sufficient-for-protection-against-all-x). Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(".question").keyup(function(){
 var question = document.forms["myForm"]["question"].value;
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://www.example.com/view_result.php",
  data: { question: question }
 })
.done(function( msg ) {
  $("#show_typing_question").html( msg );
 });
});
</script>
```

Here is the view_result.php script:

```
<?php
 function html_converter($val)
  {
    $turned = array('`&lt;b&gt;','`&lt;/b&gt;','`&lt;mark&gt;','`&lt;/mark&gt;');
    $turn_back = array('<b>','</b>','<mark style="background-color:#999;">','</mark>');
    $val = str_replace( $turned, $turn_back, $val );
    $val = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n\n", $val);
    return $val;
  }
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  $question = htmlspecialchars($question, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  echo html_converter($question);
?>
```

How can I write the whole script only in jquery function without using ajax. Is this script safe?

Comment: jquery .text() escapes all html tags including the tags mentioned in the $turned variable. Only .html() works for html tags of $turned variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to simply avoid XSS attacks client-side.  I think you are currently using PHP as a way to "clean" your question data coming from the user.  If this is not what you are asking, please clarify your question.

If you want to use text from a user, don't use `.html()` to set it, simply use `.text()`:

```
$('.question').keyup(function(){
  var question = document.forms['myForm']['question'].value;
  $('#show_typing_question').text(question);
});
```

Then, no escaping is necessary since you're using text in a text context.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear with <b>.html()</b> and <b>.text()</b>. I am trying to only display the question what is typed by the user in a textarea field and I want that the whole input should be escaped except some mentioned in the $turned array().

Comment: This ajax system causes some problems when a user types fast. Is it possible to do the whole things only in jquery so that no load is needed?

Comment: Did you try my answer?  It does what you want.