# How to use htmlspecialchars() function on a php contact form (that is using the mail() function)

Tags: php, html, forms, htmlspecialchars

I have a php contact form, which is sending data via email, and would like to sanitise it. I understand the php method for this is done with the `htmlspecialchars(`) function.

I'm new to php and can't seem to work out how to apply this to my contact from data? Do I put my `mail()` function inside it?

Any assistance would be awesome.

PHP

```
if($_POST['submit']) {

    if(!$_POST['name']) {
        $error="<br>- Please enter your name";
    }
    if(!$_POST['email']) {
        $error.="<br>- Please enter your email";
    }
    if(!$_POST['telephone']) {
        $error.="<br>- Please enter your telephone number";
    }
    if(!$_POST['message']) {
        $error.="<br>- Please enter your message";
    }
    if(!$_POST['radio']) {
        $error.="<br>- Please confirm you agree to the Privacy Policy";
    }

    if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert error">Whoops, there is an error. Please correct the following: '.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        mail("example@example.com", "Contact Message", "Name: ".$_POST['name']."
        Email: ".$_POST['email']."
        Telephone: ".$_POST['telephone']."
        Company: ".$_POST['company']."
        Budget: ".$_POST['budget']."
        Message: ".$_POST['message']);

        {
            $_POST= array();
            $result='<div class="alert thankyou" role="alert">THANK YOU! WE\'LL BE IN TOUCH SHORTLY...</div>';
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `htmlspecialchars()` function is used for escaping special characters to prevent possible XSS attacks if you use this function the correct way. You may want to use this function for the `message`.

For example:

```
mail("example@example.com", "Contact Message", "Name: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])."
    Email: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])."
    Telephone: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['telephone'])."
    Company: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['company'])."
    Budget: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['budget'])."
    Message: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

    {
        $_POST= array();
        $result='<div class="alert thankyou" role="alert">THANK YOU! WE\'LL BE IN TOUCH SHORTLY...</div>';
    }
```

Any html you have in your message will be escaped. I suggest you to read this article aswell to get a full understanding on how to use this function properly. [When used correctly, is htmlspecialchars sufficient for protection against all XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584189/when-used-correctly-is-htmlspecialchars-sufficient-for-protection-against-all-x)

Comment: @TheChewy Have you changed `example@example.com` to the email address of yourself? Check the manual for [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)