# XSS: json_encode() with or without htmspecialchars() in PHP

Tags: php, security, encoding, xss

I have seen multiple posts/examples where `json_encode()` is used within `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS when using PHP in JavaScript embedded in HTML. Still, I have also seen examples where only `json_encode()` is seen to be sufficient. For example:

```
// already sufficient?
<script type="application/json">
    <? echo json_encode($value, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>
</script>

// overkill?
<script type="application/json">
    <? echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); ?>
</script>
```

As discussed in:

[When used correctly, is htmlspecialchars sufficient for protection against all XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584189/when-used-correctly-is-htmlspecialchars-sufficient-for-protection-against-all-x)

[Is json_encode Sufficient XSS Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062146/is-json-encode-sufficient-xss-protection)

[Json: PHP to JavaScript safe or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816787/json-php-to-javascript-safe-or-not/6817147#6817147)

Is there any additional protection htmlspecialchars() would provide in this case above? And if so, would the reverted appliance `json_encode(htmlspecialchars());` instead of `htmlspecialchars(json_encode());` also work? (As I apply `htmlspecialchars()` on all strings of the user data object beforehand and would apply `json_encode()` later only for strings embedded in script tags.)

Additional Question:

I use `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` on all of my output strings containing user data. And my website saves extensive user data varying from strings containing emails, URLs, special characters, e.t.c.

Apart from HTML tags, will this break any other format and distort the correct display for the end-user? Are there specific occurrences on which I should put my focus?

For example, I saw that `urlencode()` should be used when handling unsafe variables that will be placed within an URL, but this is not relevant in my case as I only save complete static URLs provided by users. But could `htmlspecialchars()` affect breaking these static URLs?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `json_encode(htmlspecialchars())` could only make sense, if the value you are trying to output is a plain string value (or can be casted into one) to begin with.

Comment: Yes, if I understood you correctly, this whole post is about the output of user data in the form of plain string values.